# Print each record to separate pdf file using certain field for filename

Tags: vba, ms-access

I want to print each record to a separate pdf file using certain field for filename.

My code's output does not show the values as shown in the pictures.
[image]

[image]

```vb
Private Sub Command_PDF_Click()
    
    Dim myrs As Recordset
    Dim myPDF, myStmt As String
    
    myStmt = "Select distinct Code1 from Query_Certificate_Eng"
    Set myrs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(myStmt)
    
    Do Until myrs.EOF
    
        myPDF = "C:\Users\93167\Desktop\Output Certificate\" & Format(myrs.Fields("Code1"), "0000000000000") & ".pdf"
    
        DoCmd.OpenReport "Certificate_Eng", acViewPreview, , "Code1" = " & myrs.Fields("").value"
    
        DoCmd.OutputTo objectType:=acOutputReport, objectName:="Certificate_Eng", outputformat:=acFormatPDF, outputfile:=myPDF, outputquality:=acExportQualityPrint
            
        DoCmd.Close
        myrs.MoveNext
    
    Loop
myrs.Close
Set myrs = Nothing
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Try `"Code1 = '" & myrs!Code1 & "'"`.

Comment: I have post as answer. Please accept it means mark as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is in your report opening criteria. So, change it to

```
"Code1 = '" & myrs!Code1 & "'"
```